# how to aggregate the text of buttons by sliding on them?

Tags: android

I have an activity filled with buttons on the screen,and each has characteer text
something like : [A] [B] [C]  etc. I need to code that when the user touches and slides his/her finger on the screen, it should aggregate the text of each touched button ,sample result should be : A + B + C = ABC . I have written some code but it does not work as intended . in  my code ,I keep the array of buttons called **buttons** to identify which button is touched at that moment , but this code just work for first touch , it is Action_Down , it realize just first button  which I touch , When I slide my finger around I cannot get other buttons texts. , So what is your suggestions ? help please . .

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++){
                if(buttons.elementAt(i).getId()==v.getId()){
                    text+=buttons.elementAt(i).getText();
                    break;
                }
        }
         break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++){
                if(buttons.elementAt(i).getId()==v.getId()){
                    text+=buttons.elementAt(i).getText();
                    break;
                }
            }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Toast.makeText(context,text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            text="";
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you think of multi touch, but your code is not.

For multi touch you need to use ACTION_POINTER_UP/DOWN. But not all devices support multi touch.

For non-multi-touch you need a more complex handling. Buttons may be selected. The join must be done explicitly.